# How to copy paste rich-text in Android 9?

Tags: 9.0-pie, copy-paste, text-editor

I'm using Android 9 on Cherry Mobile Flare S8 Pro, and it seems I'm unable to paste rich text on an online rich text editor.

For example, I'm copying a header and bold text within rich text format then when I paste it in any Online Rich Text Editor, but it only pastes plain text without the header and bold formatting.

The problem is, this kind of workaround actually works in my Windows 10 laptop but not on my Android 9 smartphone.

I have tried downloading some copy-paste apps in playstore and using them to copy paste the formatted rich text but it doesn't work either and gives the same result.

Is there any way to deal with this without rooting my phone?

Comment: This can also depend on the used JavaScript based online rich text editor component. I have seen really dumb and badly working versions (e.g. sourceforge.net forumns is a really bad example...).